# Do different threads in a process run on different physical cores of a multi-core processor need to assign contexts?

Tags: linux, multithreading, multicore, cpu-cache

A process is the smallest unit for allocating resources. The thread is the smallest scheduling unit.

> Does this mean that a process contains at least one thread? Is the
> thread equal to the process when there is only one thread in the
> process?

Many processors today are multi-core. Join I have a process P. There are two threads in this process P, A and B. I want A and B to run on core 0 and core 1 of a CPU respectively.

But we know that the process needs to be allocated resources. The process has the context. Is the context generally stored in a register? If so, different physical cores use different physical registers. Then when thread A and thread B run on Core 0 and Core 1, respectively.

So do these two cores need to allocate resources? In this case, how do these two threads maintain consistency?  Each thread has its own resources, so hasn't this become two processes? Does this mean that different threads in a process running on different cores are the same as different processes running on different cores?

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of resources in an SMP system with the exception of registers and processing capacity are shared across all cores. This includes memory. So the operating system can schedule multiple threads on different cores, but all pointing to a shared set of process resources in memory.

CPU Caches are handled by the cores, using a cache coherency protocol. So long as the thread follows the memory model with correct use of memory barriers/atomic instructions, the memory visible through the cache should appear to be the same to all cores.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added some details

Comment: @Yujie That is a seperate question, SMT is a different concept with hardware threads which are a completely different concept from software threads. If you are confused by that, please ask that as a seperate question or I will have to vote to close your edit as needs more focus.